# how to retrieve group SMS for all the phones in android?

Tags: android, sms

I have a quick question about group sms.

I have 4 devices like Samsung S4 (5.0),Galaxy Nexus(4.3),LG Nexus(5.0),HTC one(4.4). I am getting individual sms's but unable to get group sms's. so I am trying to check the group SMS columns in the each phone to find an alternative solution but i was able to see different columns for each phone. Do you have any idea about how we can retrieve group SMS for all the phones?

Here is the code i used to get the column names and the data for all the phones.

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    String[] projection = { "*" };
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, null,
            null, "date");

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            for(int i=0;i<cur.getColumnCount();i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.d(cur.getColumnName(i),cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(cur.getColumnName(i))));
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
    }
```

Looking forward for help.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "group" SMS. Messaging apps have to add that functionality themselves. You'll notice that when you receive a group message in Android that it is actually an MMS message.

The way you want to get information about group messages is with the CONTENT_CONVERSATIONS_URI in the android.provider.Telephony.MmsSms provider instead of the android.provider.Telephony.Sms one you are using now. Use the android.provider.Telephony.MmsSms.CONTENT_CONVERSATIONS_URI instead of "content://sms/"